# Calculating shipping & handling - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to accomplish the following problem:

> Many companies normally charge a shipping and handling charge for purchases. Create a Web page that allows a user to enter a purchase price into a text box and includes a JavaScript function that calculates shipping and handling. Add functionality to the script that adds a minimum shipping and handling charge of $1.50 for any purchase that is less than or equal to $25.00. For any orders over $25.00, add 10% to the total purchase price for shipping and handling, but do not include the $1.50 minimum shipping and handling charge. The formula for calculating a percentage is price * percent / 100. For example, the formula for calculating 10% of a $50.00 purchase price is 50 * 10 / 100, which results in a shipping and handling charge of $5.00. After you determine the total cost of the order (purchase plus shipping and handling), display it in an alert dialog box.

Here's my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA [*/

//Shipping & handling fee
    var price = 0;
    var shipping = 0;
    var total = price + shipping;
    function calculateShipping(price){
    //Add $1.50 with any purchase that is less than or equal to $25.00
    if (price <= 25){
     return 1.5;
    }
    //Add 10% with any purchase that is greater than $25.00 but do not inlcude the $1.50 fee
    else{
     return price * 10 / 100
    }
    }


/* ]]> */
```

.. and my HTML

```
<form>
    <table>
    <p>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter purchase price</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="inputPrice" size="6" onchange="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Shipping &amp; handling</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td><input type="button" name="calcShipping" value="Calculate" onchange="" /></td>
    </p>
    </table>
</form>
```

I wanna go the extra mile and I'd like to show the shipping & handling fee prior to clicking the Calculate button, in other words, as soon as I type the purchase price, the S&H price appears and then, when clicking the button, the alert dialog box show my total price.

P.S. I still have problems with how to call functions :S

Comment: the problem looks artificial enough and sounds like homework ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an onkeyup event handler to the input where you've got your price, i.e.

```
onkeyup="calculateFee()"
```

This will call the calculateFee() function every time the user releases a key while in that field.

Alternatively, you can use onchange instead of onkeyup, which will wait until the focus exits the field.

Comment: (Don’t put `javascript:` in event handlers like that.)

Comment: @JoseD Sorry, I was talking to Asmor. :)